# Can't print from Libre Office 4

Tags: 13.04, libreoffice

Recently I bought a new printer, a Canon Pixma iP7250 which connects
via wi-fi. I installed it using the supplied Canon drivers for Linux
and I can print wirelessly without problem from every program in
Ubuntu except Libre Office. When I try to print a document (either
existing or new, either a .odt or a .doc) the printer icon shows for
about 10 seconds and then disappears. Going into ‘view print queue’
and looking at the document I just tried to print, it says ‘job
completed’, but when I press the refresh button it momentarily says
‘printer not found’. If I save the document as a pdf, it prints fine
from pdf viewer, but this can only be a temporary workaround. I also
have the same version of Libre Office on an old Windoze machine
running XP and I can print from that without any problem, so this must
be an Ubuntu issue. I am running 13.04.

I have looked both in the printer settings and the printer settings
within Libre Office and cannot see anything untoward. In have also
searched the internet via Duck Duck Go and even, in desperation, used
Messrs Page & Brin’s search engine, but I could not find anything on
this particular issue.

I would be very grateful for any advice on this issue, as I tend to
print more from Libre Office than any other program.

Thanks

Comment: Would you kindly report on your current version of LibreOffice?

Comment: Hi, yes, it's 4.0.2.2

Comment: Check the paper size in both page size in Format --> Page, and  paper size in File --> Printer Settings.

Comment: Both are set to A4.

Comment: LO appears not to see the printer at all.

Comment: Tried uninstalling and re-installing LO with a newer version, but to no avail. Printer is definitely seen by LO and all the right boxes are ticked, but when printing from any LO module, the printer icon goes after 10 seconds. Going into the print queue it says printer not connected when it is - via wifi and switched on.

Answer (score 1):

After having said that everything else prints except LO, I discovered that I could not print a photograph today and the problem was the same - 'printer not connected'. I solved it by deleting the printer, connecting it via USB and re-installing it as a local printer. Now it prints from LO, photos, Firefox etc. Wi fi connection just doesn't work on Ubuntu.